# How to enable javascript while connecting to a URL with HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, javascript, https, salesforce, httpsurlconnection

I am trying to access a salesforce URL through frontdoor JSP to get the HTML content using HttpsURLConnection. I am able to get the HTML content for all other websites except salesforce.

I get back an error that says "You do not have Javascript enabled". Is there a work around?

Comment: Where are you running the JSP from -- your IDE or a real browser? Or are you just calling some URL from Java code?

Comment: Am invoking the URL from Java using a httpsUTLConnection